# \nomname undefined when list of symbols is in a external file

Tags: external-files, include, nomenclature, nomencl

I want to create a list of symbols in an external file using the `nomencl` package. Here's what my file `listOfSymbols.tex` looks like:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\nomenclature{$v$}{volume fraction}
\nomenclature{$\nu$}{kinematic viscosity}
\nomenclature{$f$}{focal length}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck's constant}
\nomenclature{$c$}{speed of light}
\printnomenclature
```

The relevant parts in the main document look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Create nomenclatures.
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\include{listOfSymbols}
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile it in Texmaker, I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: \nomname undefined.`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm new to LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @StefanBraun. Thank you, I made the requested edit.

Comment: @Dave But you are using `glossaries` package instead of `nomencl` package. That is why the error.

Comment: @JagathAR Oh you're right, I mixed things up badly.. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Dave: Indeed, you mixed `glossaries` and `nomencl`. `glossaries` does not have `\printnomenclature` and the `\include` style is perhaps not the best way to use the list of symbols

Comment: @JagathAR: Perhaps, you should provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

The commands `\nomname`, `\nomenclature{}{}` and `\printnomenclature` are defined in the package `nomencl`. Hence, you should use:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}
```

in the preamble.